# Not getting expected result using descriptor in Python

Tags: python, descriptor

I am new to Python...was trying some code with Descriptor and running below code to change Fahrenheit to Celsius.
But I am not getting the exact result. Can some one assist, how is it working?

Tried below code

```
import sys
import os

class Celsius:
    def __get__(self, obj, owner):
        return self.celsius

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        self.celsius = (value-32)*5/9

class Temperature:
    celsius = Celsius()

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.fahrenheit = f

t1 = Temperature(32)
t1.celsius = 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
        t1 = Temperature(int(input()))
        print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
```

Expected result: (212, 100.0) (As per formula)
actual result: (212, -17.77777777777778)
How is it calculating -17?

Comment: How? From here: `t1.celsius = 0` ; -32*5/9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not initialize `t1.celsius` with 0, but instead make use of `celsius`'s setter in `Temperature.__init__`:

```
class Temperature:
    celsius = Celsius()

    def __init__(self, f):
        self.fahrenheit = self.celsius = f
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/UsableSunnyConfig

Comment: Thanks for quick response...it is working now...but why are we assigning fahrenheit  to celsius.....it should come through Celsius Object/class?

Comment: Glad to be of help. This is because you've made the `Celsius` descriptor class' setter to convert fahrenheit to celsius. We assign fahrenheit to celsius to actually make use of this setter.

Answer (score 0):

```
t1.celsius = 0
```

This is your mistake. You're creating Celsius class with zero value, so the setter sets (0 - 32)*5/9 that is - 17.777777777778

Comment: Pass the value to Celsius class too when you take it in input

Comment: Please add to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple Temperature manager that handles conversations of :Kelvin,Fahrenheit,Celsius

```
class Temperature:
    def __init__(self, value, unit='C'):
        self.value = value
        if unit.upper() in ['C', 'F', 'K']:
            self.unit = unit.upper()
        else:
            raise ValueError('Unit must be C|F|K')

    @property
    def kelvin(self):
        if self.unit == 'K':
            return self.value
        elif self.unit == 'C':
            return self.value - 273.15
        else:
            return (self.value - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32

    @property
    def celsius(self):
        if self.unit == 'C':
            return self.value
        elif self.unit == 'K':
            return self.value + 273.15
        else:
            return (self.value * 9 / 5) + 32

    @property
    def fahrenheit(self):
        if self.unit == 'F':
            return self.value
        elif self.unit == 'C':
            return (self.value - 32) * 5 / 9
        else:
            return (self.value - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15


t = Temperature(7,'k')
print(t.fahrenheit)
```